# why my captions are not showing at the center of slider image

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create my slider by using css animation properties. for this i have created slider which is  working but when i tried to add captions its working too but caption are showing below the slider images not at center of the images even i added absolute position. here is my code. i also gave relative position to its parent div but still not working

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#fullwrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}



/*=========================Slider Style======================*/

@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

@keyframes caps {
0% { left: 0%; float: none; }
20% { left: 0%; float: none;}
25% { left: -100%; float: none;}
45% { left: -100%; float: none;}
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}












#slider { overflow: hidden;  }
#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 

}

#captions{
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 width: 500%;
   animation: 30s caps infinite; 

}

.caption{
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
 font-size: xx-large;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
 font-variant: small-caps;
}




/*=========================Slider Style======================*/
#navbar{
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<div id="fullwrapper">  <!-- Start of Full Body Wrapper-->
 <div id="header">   <!-- Start of of Header-->
  <div id="slider">



        <figure>
             <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
             
             <img src="taj-mahal_copy.jpg" alt>
   
             <img src="ibiza.jpg" alt>
            
             <img src="ankor-wat.jpg" alt>
        
             <img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
        </figure>
    

<div id="navbar">
 <nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
 </nav>
 
</div>

<figure id="captions">
<span class="caption">some caption text 1</span>
<span class="caption">some caption text 2</span>
<span class="caption">some caption text 3</span>
<span class="caption">some caption text 4</span>
<span class="caption">some caption text 5</span>
</figure>
</div>

 </div><!-- End  of Header-->   

</div> <!-- End of Full Body Wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. I wrapped the caption div in one other div then I set it to use absolute position and it is working fine.